# General Gaussian integral in Peskin and Schroeder

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, path-integral, integration, linear-algebra

I'm working on the Eq. (9.24) in Peskin & Schroeder.

[image]

[image]

I tried to derive it but I have difficulties.

I canʻt follow this step:
$$
\left(\prod_{k} \int d \xi_{k}\right) \exp \left[-\xi_{i} B_{i j} \xi_{j}\right]=\left(\prod_{k} \int d x_{k}\right) \exp \left[-\sum_{i} b_{i} x_{i}^{2}\right].
$$
 Here's my derivation:
\begin{align}
\left(\prod_{k} \int d \xi_{k}\right) \exp \left[-\xi_{i} B_{i j} \xi_{j}\right]=\left(\prod_{l}
 \int d O_{k l} x_{l}\right) \exp \left[-O_{i j} x_{j} B_{j \sigma} O_{\sigma \rho} x_{\rho}\right].
\end{align}
Now how to go on?

Comment: It’s a similarity transform of $B$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you find an orthogonal matrix that diagonalizes $\mathbf{B}$

$$\mathbf{B} = \mathbf{O}^T\mathbf{DO} \qquad B_{ij} = (O_{ik})^TD_{kl}O_{lj}$$

where $\mathbf{D}$ is a diagional matrix. Putting it in the integral

$$\left(\prod_{k} \int d \xi_{k}\right) \exp \left[-\xi_{i} B_{i j} \xi_{j}\right]=\left(\prod_{k}
 \int d\xi_k\right) \exp \left[-O_{i j} \xi_{j} D_{j \sigma} O_{\sigma \rho} \xi_{\rho}\right]$$

Now you can do the following coordinate change which will have unitary Jacobian being $\mathbf{O}$ an orthogonal matrix

$$\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{O\xi}\qquad d\mathbf{x}=d\mathbf{\xi}$$

so that the integral becomes

$$\left(\prod_k\int dx_k\right)\exp[-x_i D_{ij}x_j] =  \left(\prod_k\int dx_k\right)\exp\left[-\sum_ix_i b_i\delta_{ij}x_j\right]\\
 = \left(\prod_k\int dx_k\right)\exp\left[-\sum_i b_ix_i^2\right] = \prod_i\left(\int dx_i \exp\left[-b_ix_i^2\right]\right)$$

since $\mathbf{D}$ is a diagonal matrix.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Besides, I have another question. B is a symmetric matrix, however, its eigenvalue ($b_i$) might be negative, why $
\int d x_{i} \exp \left[-b_{i} x_{i}^{2}\right]=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{b_{i}}}$?

Comment: Yes, you're right! I would think that $B$ has to be considered as a measurable quantity, so the eigenvalues are real and positive.